# Writing to Oracle from NLog

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, asp.net-core, nlog

So I've got a database target to write logs to an Oracle database table but I cannot seem to get it to write to the table. I've tried various dbProviders and usually get an error like below

```
    <target name="database" xsi:type="Database" connectionString="${var:ConnectionStrings}"     dbProvider="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess"
        commandType="Text" keepConnection="false"
        commandText="INSERT INTO SAMS.LOG    (ID,  LOGLEVEL, MESSAGE, LOGGER, CALLSITE, EXCEPTIONDETAIL, USERNAME, IPADDRESS)
    VALUES('',  
    :LogLevel,
    :Message,
    :Logger,
    :Callsite,
    :ExceptionType,
    :UserName,
    :IpAddress);"  >
  <parameter name="Logged" layout="${date}" />

  <parameter name="LogLevel" layout="${level}" />
  <parameter name="Message" layout="url: ${aspnet-request-url} | action: ${aspnet-mvc-action} | ${message}" />
  <parameter name="Logger" layout="${logger}" />
  <parameter name="Callsite" layout="${callsite:filename=true}" />
  <parameter name="ExceptionType" layout="${exception:tostring}" />
  <parameter name="UserName" layout="${aspnet-user-identity}" />
   <parameter name="IpAddress" layout=" ${aspnet-request-ip}" />

</target>
```

This is the furthest I've been able to get to in the process. It has attempted to write to the database but something is off in my connection string.

```
        2018-10-23 14:13:28.1934 Error DatabaseTarget(Name=database_wrapped): Error when writing to database. Exception: Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor ---> OracleInternal.Network.NetworkException (0x000030E2): ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
       at OracleInternal.Network.OracleCommunication.DoConnect(String tnsDescriptor)
       at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.Connect(ConnectionString cs, Boolean bOpenEndUserSession, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String instanceName)
       at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.Get(ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
       at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.Get(ConnectionString csWithNewPassword, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
       at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionDispenser`3.Get(ConnectionString cs, PM conPM, ConnectionString pmCS, SecureString securedPassword, SecureString securedProxyPassword, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria)
       at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
       at NLog.Targets.DatabaseTarget.OpenConnection(String connectionString)
       at NLog.Targets.DatabaseTarget.EnsureConnectionOpen(String connectionString)
       at NLog.Targets.DatabaseTarget.WriteEventToDatabase(LogEventInfo logEvent)
       at NLog.Targets.DatabaseTarget.Write(IList`1 logEvents)
```

My appsettings.json contains the connection string

```
     "ConnectionStrings": {
        "NLogDb": "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP) 
   (HOST=fleetqadb.xxx.com)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA= 
   (SERVICE_NAME=orcl.fleetqadb.xxx.com)));User 
    Id=samsuser;Password=xxxxx;",
      }
```

If anyone has any ideas, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know *NLog*, but `ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor` means that the database you want to insert data to is *unknown*.

If it was pure Oracle, I'd say that database's alias doesn't exist in the TNSNAMES.ORA

In your case, you provided `"ConnectionString"` (mind you: at the beginning of your message, you call it a `connectionString`, while at the end of the message you call it `ConnectionStrings` - note the trailing `s`, as well as letter case. I don't know which one (or both?) of those matters).

"Data source" *is* the database you're trying to connect to. Apparently, what you wrote in there is invalid.

I have the TNSNAMES.ORA and can `tnsping` my database as

```
C:\>tnsping xe

TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 23-LIS-2018 21:07:09

Copyright (c) 1997, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\Users\lf\Documents\E_0_library\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = lflp.dt.center)(
PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XE)))
OK (10 msec)
```

I'm not a DBA, but - check your `host` and `service_name` values.

My suggestion: as a `service_name`, put `orcl` only (instead of `orcl.fleetqadb.xxx.com`) and see what happens.